# Greek and Latin letters in verbatim

Tags: babel, verbatim, greek

I want to write a code snippet where the commands are in greek and variables are in latin. I use the verbatim command but automatically the latin characters are translated to their greek equivalent.
I use the babel package so far and I had no issues.

```
\begin{verbatim}
για κάθε t:
    x1 = x0 + u*Δt
\end{verbatim}
```

which results in

[image]

In the preamble I use

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
\usepackage[LGR, T1]{fontenc}
```

Any ideas on how to fix that? I would like not to change to another package like `polyglossia` because that would make me to rewrite a big portion of my report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was fixed after refactoring the `\usepackage` command:

`\usepackage[english, greek]{babel}`

and inserting the command

`\selectlanguage{english}` before the verbatim

Answer (score 6):

Set the font encoding to T1 inside `verbatim`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{alphabeta}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\verbatim@font{\normalfont\fontencoding{T1}\ttfamily}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
για κάθε t:
    x1 = x0 + u*Δt
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]